# Document Moved Error when using web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have a windows application where i added a web service to sharepoint Lists.asmx.

When i am using the GetListItemChangesSinceToken() method i get an error:

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://localhost:333/Test/Forms/AllItems.aspx">here</a></body>
--.
```

I am calling the method like this:

```
public XmlNode GetListItems()
{
 XmlNode getFirstToken = null;
 try
 {
  getFirstToken = listService.GetListItemChangesSinceToken(
                           listName, null, null, null, null, null, currentToken, null);
 }
            ...
}
```

where listName equal the guid of the list, and the list name is "Test".

Any one have an idea what that error means? How to solve it?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is that your web-service is in the same web application with your Sharepoint.
In this case Sharepoint intercepts the request handle from IIS and try to resolve it by himself. But it can't do it, and redirects you to its default page.
Move your web-service out of Sharepoint site in IIS and try again.

---

Update:
According to your comments, address of `listService` object equals the default address for your sharepoint site. So you should get the real address of service, ending with `.asmx`, and set it to your `listService` object.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "web-service is in the same web application with your Sharepoint" can you explain more?

Comment: You have an IIS, right? You have an installed Sharepoint there. And you have an web-service running there. You should move this applications to different sites in IIS.

Comment: @Moussa Then check the URL of your `listService` object. It seems it has wrong value.

Comment: The list service url is the url of the list in sharepoint: "http:[double slash]localhost:333/Test"

Comment: @Moussa URL of the service must ends with `.asmx`. `http://localhost:333/Test` - is a address of your sharepoint site. So you use the wrong url for your service

Comment: @ShefaliChaudhari If you have a new question, you should ask it, please, do not write comments with questions. According to your error message, you're trying to access a resource without authorization. Add credentials to your request

Answer (score 0):

Please check that web service 'url' is correct and it is not affected by redirection in the target website. (for ex, if non-www requests are being directed to www, and you are using non-www format, you may experience this problem)